# Return a specific bitmap instead of whole view in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an `ImageView` and in that `ImageView`. I have two bitmaps in that `ImageView` and I want to do something with one bitmap. But I am not able to do it. I am able to access the whole view but not the specific  bitmap. My Method to access whole view

```
private Bitmap bitmap() {
        try {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) image_holder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

let's say I have two bitmaps b1 & b2 and I want to return b1 in the method how to do that?

Comment: `I have two bitmaps in that ImageView`. An ImageView can hold only one bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you know sizes of you Bitmaps I Think you can use

`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)` to split bitmap you got with known size.

For example your imageview size is 10x10 and contains two bitmaps:

```
b1.createBitmap(Bitmap,0,0,5,10);
b2.createBitmap(Bitmap,5,0,5,10);
```